# Мавен не создает property

Tags: java, maven, properties

В файле `pom.xml` есть такая конструкция

```
<properties>
            <datasource>jdbc/${project.artifactId}DS</datasource>
</properties>
```

Потом этот datasourse используется в `setting.properties` проекта

```
datasourceName=${datasource}
```

Проблема в том, что в `setting.properties` этот `datasource` через раз равен `null`.

Почему так? с мавеном что-то не то? Хотя пробовал разные версии

Comment: Если вы используете спринг бут, то надо оборачивать через @datasource@

Answer (score 0):

`Properties` клас не может транслировать такие значения как `${datasource}`.

Можно использовать [properties-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) для чтения/записи свойств из/в файл(а).